# How to show image with animation in UIImageView in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation

I am using swift to load a image from photo library. And add that image on a UIImageView. I want to show the image animated by running below code but it doesn't have any effect. The image is shown immediately after selection. Does anyone know what I should use in this case?

```
func imagePickerController(_picker: UIImagePickerController,
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){
        imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
        self.photoView.alpha = 0;
        self.photoView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage;
        UIImageView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
            self.photoView.alpha = 1;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It almost seems like there is an internal issue with the animation loop being access from within this delegate method. I looked into a few options and the solution below `dispatch_after()` is the only option that worked for me for all my test cases.

Note: I'm not saying this is pretty or the final answer. Just reporting my findings and what works for me. The `UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay:0, options:[.ShowHideTransitionViews]...` solution only worked for me on iOS8 not iOS9. YMMV

```
func imagePickerController(_picker: UIImagePickerController,
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){
        _picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        self.imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        self.imageView.alpha = 0

        let shortDelay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1_000))
        dispatch_after(shortDelay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
                self.imageView.alpha = 1.0
            }
        }

//        // Does not work. No animation of alpha.
//            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
//                self.imageView.alpha = 1.0
//            }

//            // Does not work. No animation of alpha.
//            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
//                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
//                self.imageView.alpha = 1.0
//            }
//            // Does not work. No animation of alpha.
//            UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay:1, options:[], animations: {
//                self.imageView.alpha = 1
//            },  completion: nil)

//            // Works iOS8 Simulator. Does not work iOS9 Simulator (9.1) or device (9.2.1).
//            UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay:0, options:[.ShowHideTransitionViews], animations: {
//                self.imageView.alpha = 1
//            }, completion: nil)

//            // Old school, does not work
//            UIView.commitAnimations()
//            UIView.beginAnimations("alphaAni", context: nil)
//            self.imageView.alpha = 1
//            UIView.commitAnimations()

}
```

Comment: dispatch_after works for me. But I don't understand why UIView.animateXXX doesn't work in this case?

Comment: I think UIView.animate() methods should work and do not see any reason why they don't. With the other difference seen between iOS8 and iOS9 it seems there is something going on under the covers that is messing this up. I'm hoping someone can explain more.

Answer (score 3):

You can try out the following code

```
self.photoView.hidden = true;
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.ShowHideTransitionViews, animations: { () -> Void in
     self.photoView.hidden = false
     }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in    }
)
```

You can add view which you want to animate inside animations block.

**EDIT**

```
self.photoView.alpha = 0
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.ShowHideTransitionViews, animations: { () -> Void in
     self.photoView.alpha = 1
     }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in    }
)
```

Changing alpha value to creating animation effect

Comment: I would recommend to change alpha value to opponent value instead of hide property.

Comment: I have tried your code but it doesn't have any effect. The image still shown immediately.

Comment: Did you try out edit i posted with alpha value change? Try changing animation duration. I tried it out locally, its working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        UIView.transition(with: self.photoView,
                          duration: 0.5,
                          options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                          animations: {
                            self.photoView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
                          },
                          completion: nil)
```